# puppeteer .Click('.classname') working only 1 time every 20 tries

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I try to click (using puppeteer) on "autres lieux à découvrir" on this google url:

https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03J9M8qkHugbBtnKYL5VCL71deV9Q%3A1589104257547&ei=gc63XvPyIIjga5bZqKgG&q=lieux+a+decouvrir+departement+Ain&oq=lieux+a+decouvrir+departement+Ain&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzoECAAQRzoHCCEQChCgAToECCEQFVDejcUEWMafxQRg_qDFBGgAcAJ4AIABfIgB5AeSAQQxMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwizt6DWgqnpAhUI8BoKHZYsCmUQ4dUDCAw&uact=5

[here a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNUus.jpg)

so on code i simply put :

```
    await page.waitForSelector('.UEBZnb');
    await page.click('.UEBZnb');
```

but when i execute it, it almost every time send me a timeout error (30 000ms waited)...
but sometimes it works just fine...
In my program i click on other places using the same lines, and it work perfectly fine.

i tried with other class format, it behave exactly the same.

Do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong actually?

Comment: provide a screenshot of what you're trying to select

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the page loaded.

```
page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000); 
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

you can set your timeout to 10 secs and try again.

Comment: isn't what does ```await page.waitForSelector('.UEBZnb');``` ? My error message isn't about the fact that it didn't found it, it's because it spent more than 30 seconds to find it (way more than 10 sec)

Comment: I think your page is not loaded yet, so you can not select that element.

Comment: i just added a line before ```await page.waitFor(20000);``` and the problem is still the same.

Comment: await page.waitFo('.UEBZnb');
can you use this instead of 
 await page.waitForSelector('.UEBZnb');

Comment: nope, still same problem. In fact i'm pretty sure it's not about the loading, i tried it with a wait of 120 seconds and it changed nothing.

Comment: can you share some more code, so I can run on my side ? Do you have skype ?

Comment: No it's okay, i just saved all the links on an array when it managed to work so i don't have to use this page again, but thanks a lot for your help